# Ember and TinyMCE

Tags: ember.js, tinymce

I want to use the TinyMCE component in an Ember app.  My basic question is: how and where can you init the tinymce ?

Template contains the textarea element:

```
<textarea class='test' name="content" style="width:100%">
```

I need to init TinyMce as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
});
```

Where do I need to do the init and how ?  In think in the controller init, but this does not work as expected ...

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    }    
});
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/wtktK/6/

Hope somebody can help ...

Comment: your jsfiddle is miss tinymce theme file `theme.js` so even if properly initialized it wont work.

Comment: Any idea how to properly add tinymce js files to JSFiddle ? It seems indeed that I am missing a large number of files (including themes, css, skins, images, etc.).  I don't think I need to add all of these manually to JSFiddle ...

Comment: Just found it; use the CDN version at //tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `tinymce.init` you must make sure that your `textarea` tag is in DOM. On the time your controller gets initialized your view (in this case `IndexView`) is not yet rendered. A valid way to wait for a view be be rendered is to use `didInsertElement` hook in that view. In your case:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  This indeed works.  I am always confused about the int, didInsertElement and other events firing at load of a template, a view, a controller, etc.

Comment: I am now strugling with the valuebinding of the TinyMCE textarea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930456/ember-how-to-valuebind-tinymce-textarea-field-to-model - Perhaps you can help ...