# Ember: How to valuebind TinyMCE textarea field to model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE embedded in a template.  Now, I want to valuebind the content of the TinyMCE editor (which is in fact a textarea).

See http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/wtktK/10/

When entering text in the textfield, the text in the {{bodyText}} is updated. I would also like to update the text in the TinyMCE textarea ...

Any idea how to do this ?

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Tiny MCE</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
        <form method="post" action="somepage">
            App.IndexController.bodyText value:</br>
            {{bodyText}}
            </br></br>

            Bound to Ember.TextField:<br>
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='bodyText'}}

            </br></br>
            Bound to Ember.TextArea:</br>
            {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding='bodyText'}}

        </form>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function () {});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ });

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    bodyText: '...' 
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: have found something similar for knockout: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---tinyMCE

Comment: Thanks. Looks very complex ... It is hard to believe that in Ember you would need an extra 150 lines compared to for example a standard jquery implementation (in which you just set and get the value of the textarea using id or css selectors). A UI framework should simplify the work of the developer and in this case I have the impression that you really need to have a deep understanding of Ember in order to fill the gaps.

Comment: Whoa, its needed a lot of code to integrate tinyMCE with other framework. My implemantition is just aware of bind changes on keyup. I would want to make better, but I don't have great knowledge in tinymce. My code is usefull for you Marc?

Comment: It looks very complex, can definitely agree on that. In my perspective it is more a tinymce issue that it does not provide hooks to combine with other libraries / frameworks. If tinymce would allow you to subscribe to something like `change` event your would be able to provide it with a reference to Ember App in a closure. The response of Márcio Rodrigues Correa Júnior looks good but it does not solve the issue as it wont support for example paste by mouse, or dropping text.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior Do you know a similar component that provides better integration with Ember ?  I agree that the implementation shown below works partially (only keyUp event supported); thus when using the toolbar buttons (e.g. set text to heading 1 - nothing happens in the bound textField) ...

Comment: @Marc I realized this now. And uptdated to use the change event. And works :)

Comment: @Marc sorry, just forget your question. I don't know some component like it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I made some changes in your fiddle.

Give a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Jw75L/26/

First I removed the `var` from App declaration, to become the `App` namespace global and visible in handlebars template.

And replaced the tinymce from `IndexView` to `TinymceView`, to be reusable.

```
App.TinymceView = Ember.TextArea.extend({
    editor: null,
    _suspendValueChange: false,
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var id = "#" + this.get("elementId");        
        var view = this;
        tinymce.init({
            selector: id,
            setup : function(ed) {                
                view.set("editor", ed);
                ed.on("keyup change", function() {
                    view.suspendValueChange(function() {
                        view.set("value", ed.getContent());
                    });
                });
           }
        });
    },
    suspendValueChange: function(cb) {
        this._suspendValueChange = true;
        cb();
        this._suspendValueChange = false;
    },
    valueChanged: function() {
        if (this._suspendValueChange) { return; }
        var content = this.get("value");
        this.get("editor").setContent(content);
    }.observes("value"),
    willClearRender: function() {        
        this.get("editor").remove();
    }
});
```

Because TinyMCE changes the textarea and create a lot of elements, I had that observer the change in the TinyMCE and propagate to the `TinymceView`, `using ditor.on("keyup"...`.

Comment: Great solution !  Just one remark: the binding should take into account html code and not pure text.  Thus, when entering <h2>XXXX</h2> in the textField, the TinyMCE should show this in h2 style (this is already correct), but when changing in TinyMCE to h1 style, the value in TextField should become <h1>XXXX</h1>.  Any idea how to solve this ?  Many thanks.

Comment: I updated. I removed the $().text(), from ed.getContent() this will make the h1 appear. And I added the change event, to update the input when the user change the content by formats -> header -> h1, by example. Because this does't trigger a keyup event.

Comment: @Marc just a last update. I added a hook 'willClearRender', to remove the editor when the view is destroyed, this is important to prevent memory leaks.Best regards!