# TinyMCE with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, tinymce

I was using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930456/ember-how-to-valuebind-tinymce-textarea-field-to-model) as a starting point to use TinyMCE with Emberjs.

The binding works great, but I encountered a strange problem, even though the code is the same: the setup method does not gets called in the `tinymce.init({...})` thus the editor object remains `undefined`. This breaks the code. I don't know if it is related, but I do not get any toolbars of the tinyMCE. My view hosting the tinyMCE is rendered as a simple textarea - maybe this this is the correct behavior.

**UPDATE**

Here is the [problem reproduced](https://github.com/CoderPio/ember-require-grunt-precompile).

Comment: can you share your view code where tinymce get's initialized?

Comment: all the code is there

Comment: can you reproduce this in a jsbin? and what version on tinymce are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.0.4. Reproducing the code in jsbin might take some time as this view is inside another view.

Comment: btw, when does the setup function get called? What is the event that triggers it?